# Read JSON file into Python Pandas - Read in without the '\'

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read a JSON file into a pandas dataframe (more specifically, the final goal is to convert JSON to CSV)

So, I have a JSON in the format:

```
["[{\\"key1\\":\\"value1\\",\\"key2\\":\\"value2\\"}]"]
```

if I use the following line, the resulting dataframe comes out in one big blob:

```
df = df.read_json(json_filename)
```

I noticed that if I manually go into the JSON file and remove all of the `\\`, then when I read it into a dataframe it works as it should. But I have a feeling I am not using the right syntax; Pandas I am sure knows how to handle the file because it is in a correct JSON format (List of JSON objects/list of dictionaries)

My idea was that I could read into a dataframe, remove all `\\` from the dataframe using `df.replace()` but then the dataframe is just one long row with no `\\` in it and not a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have double-encoded Json. Try using `json` module to decode it:

```py
import json

with open("your_file.txt", "r") as f_in:
    data = json.load(f_in)
    data = json.loads(data[0])

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     key1    key2
0  value1  value2
```